Redirect not working in if/else but working in some part of the code
In This code Line 62 & 65 where i have commented out { Redirect(concat(@loginPageURL,"?invalidtoken=",1,"&referer=",@referer)) }
The code does not work when i include these line in my code.
why is  Redirect(concat(@loginPageURL,"?invalidtoken=",1,"&referer=",@referer)) not working because same function is working on the line 50 or 52 {Redirect(concat(@loginPageURL,"?invalidpass=",1,"&referer=",@referer))}
Can someone give me a reason why is this behaving this way and what can be the workaround?
%%[

 SET @loginPageURL = "https://mc5g1jyy4qkqlgb-cvw66g-1m5w4.pub.sfmc-content.com/3wgupd41ruu"
 
 SET @username = RequestParameter("username")
 SET @pass = RequestParameter("pass")
 SET @token = RequestParameter("token")
 SET @referer = RequestParameter("referer")
 SET @today = SystemDateToLocalDate(NOW())
 
 SET @TriggeredSendExternalKey = "27581"
 
 IF NOT EMPTY(@username) AND NOT EMPTY(@pass) AND NOT EMPTY(@referer) THEN
        SET @rows = LookupRows("Users","Username",@username,"Password",@pass)
        IF RowCount(@rows) > 0 THEN
           SET @Id = Field(Row(@rows,1), 'Id')
           SET @Email = Field(Row(@rows,1), 'Email')
        ENDIF
        IF NOT EMPTY(@Id) AND NOT EMPTY(@Email) THEN
           SET @token = GUID()
        
           UpsertDE("Tokens",1,"Id",@Id,"Token",@token,"Referer",@referer,"CreatedDate",@today)
        
           SET @TriggeredSend = CreateObject("TriggeredSend")
           SET @TriggeredSendDefinition = CreateObject("TriggeredSendDefinition")
           SetObjectProperty(@TriggeredSendDefinition, "CustomerKey", @TriggeredSendExternalKey)
           SetObjectProperty(@TriggeredSend, "TriggeredSendDefinition", @TriggeredSendDefinition)
        
           SET @TriggeredSendSubscriber = CreateObject("Subscriber")
           SetObjectProperty(@TriggeredSendSubscriber, "EmailAddress", @Email)
           SetObjectProperty(@TriggeredSendSubscriber, "SubscriberKey", @Email)
        
           SET @tkn = CreateObject("Attribute")
           SetObjectProperty(@tkn, "Name", "Token")
           SetObjectProperty(@tkn,"Value", @token)
           AddObjectArrayItem(@TriggeredSend, "Attributes", @tkn)
        
           SET @ref = CreateObject("Attribute")
           SetObjectProperty(@ref, "Name", "Referer")
           SetObjectProperty(@ref,"Value", @referer)
           AddObjectArrayItem(@TriggeredSend, "Attributes", @ref)
        
           AddObjectArrayItem(@TriggeredSend, "Subscribers", @TriggeredSendSubscriber)
        
           SET @TriggeredSend_statusCode = InvokeCreate(@TriggeredSend, @TriggeredSend_statusMsg, @errorCode)
        
           IF @TriggeredSend_statusCode != "OK" THEN
               RaiseError(@TriggeredSend_statusMsg, 0, @TriggeredSend_statusCode, @errorCode)
           ENDIF
           Redirect(concat(@loginPageURL,"?istokensent=",1,"&referer=",@referer))
        ELSE
           Redirect(concat(@loginPageURL,"?invalidpass=",1,"&referer=",@referer))
        ENDIF
        
 ELSEIF NOT EMPTY(@token) THEN
        SET @createdDate = Lookup("Tokens","CreatedDate","Token",@token)
        
        IF NOT EMPTY(@createdDate) AND @today < DateAdd(@createdDate, 1, "D")  THEN
           SET @endDate = DateAdd(@today, 1, "D")
           Redirect(CONCAT(@referer))
        ELSE
           /* Redirect(concat(@loginPageURL,"?invalidtoken=",1,"&referer=",@referer)) */ 
        ENDIF
 ELSE
           /* Redirect(concat(@loginPageURL,"?invalidtoken=",1,"&referer=",@referer)) */
 ENDIF
]%%
          <script runat="server">
              Platform.Load("core","1.1");
              var endDateStr = Platform.Variable.GetValue("@endDate");
              var token = Platform.Variable.GetValue("@token");
  
              var endDate = new Date(endDateStr);
              // Get individual components of the date and time
              var year = endDate.getUTCFullYear();
              var month = ('0' + (endDate.getUTCMonth() + 1)).slice(-2); // Add leading zero if needed
              var day = ('0' + endDate.getUTCDate()).slice(-2); // Add leading zero if needed
              var hours = ('0' + endDate.getUTCHours()).slice(-2); // Add leading zero if needed
              var minutes = ('0' + endDate.getUTCMinutes()).slice(-2); // Add leading zero if needed
              var seconds = ('0' + endDate.getUTCSeconds()).slice(-2); // Add leading zero if needed
              var milliseconds = ('00' + endDate.getUTCMilliseconds()).slice(-3); // Add leading zero if needed
  
              var formattedEndDate = year + '-' + month + '-' + day + 'T' + hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds + '.' + milliseconds + 'Z';
  
              Platform.Response.SetCookie("userlg", token, formattedEndDate , true);
          </script>


What's the intent with this line Redirect(CONCAT(@referer))?

Why are you redirecting in the middle of your code and not at the end?  I'd expect it to behave inconsistently just because of that.
Also, what are you expecting from the raiseError() if the triggered send fails?  I don't think a CloudPage is an appropriate context for that function.
I'd suggest using some debugging output to trace variable values and the flow of the page.  Something like this:
%%[

 set @debug = 1
 SET @loginPageURL = "https://mc5g1jyy4qkqlgb-cvw66g-1m5w4.pub.sfmc-content.com/3wgupd41ruu"
 SET @username = RequestParameter("username")
 SET @pass = RequestParameter("pass")
 SET @token = RequestParameter("token")
 SET @referer = RequestParameter("referer")
 SET @today = SystemDateToLocalDate(NOW())
 SET @TriggeredSendExternalKey = "27581"
 set @redirectURL = @loginPageURL

 if @debug == 1 then
  output(concat("<br>username: ", @username))
  output(concat("<br>pass: ", @pass))
  output(concat("<br>token: ", @token))
  output(concat("<br>referer: ", @referer))
  output(concat("<br>today: ", @today))
 endif
 
 IF NOT EMPTY(@username) AND NOT EMPTY(@pass) AND NOT EMPTY(@referer) THEN

        if @debug == 1 then
         output(concat("<br>username, pass and referer exist"))
        endif

        SET @rows = LookupRows("Users","Username",@username,"Password",@pass)
        set @rowcount = RowCount(@rows)

        if @debug == 1 then
         output(concat("<br>rowcount: ", @rowcount))
        endif

        IF @rowcount > 0 THEN
           SET @Id = Field(Row(@rows,1), 'Id')
           SET @Email = Field(Row(@rows,1), 'Email')
        ENDIF

        if @debug == 1 then
         output(concat("<br>Id: ", @Id))
         output(concat("<br>Email: ", @Email))
        endif

        IF NOT EMPTY(@Id) AND NOT EMPTY(@Email) THEN

           SET @token = GUID()
        
           UpsertDE("Tokens",1,"Id",@Id,"Token",@token,"Referer",@referer,"CreatedDate",@today)
        
           SET @TriggeredSend = CreateObject("TriggeredSend")
           SET @TriggeredSendDefinition = CreateObject("TriggeredSendDefinition")
           SetObjectProperty(@TriggeredSendDefinition, "CustomerKey", @TriggeredSendExternalKey)
           SetObjectProperty(@TriggeredSend, "TriggeredSendDefinition", @TriggeredSendDefinition)
        
           SET @TriggeredSendSubscriber = CreateObject("Subscriber")
           SetObjectProperty(@TriggeredSendSubscriber, "EmailAddress", @Email)
           SetObjectProperty(@TriggeredSendSubscriber, "SubscriberKey", @Email)
        
           SET @tkn = CreateObject("Attribute")
           SetObjectProperty(@tkn, "Name", "Token")
           SetObjectProperty(@tkn,"Value", @token)
           AddObjectArrayItem(@TriggeredSend, "Attributes", @tkn)
        
           SET @ref = CreateObject("Attribute")
           SetObjectProperty(@ref, "Name", "Referer")
           SetObjectProperty(@ref,"Value", @referer)
           AddObjectArrayItem(@TriggeredSend, "Attributes", @ref)
        
           AddObjectArrayItem(@TriggeredSend, "Subscribers", @TriggeredSendSubscriber)
        
           SET @TriggeredSend_statusCode = InvokeCreate(@TriggeredSend, @TriggeredSend_statusMsg, @errorCode)
        
           if @debug == 1 then
            output(concat("<br>TriggeredSend_statusCode: ", @TriggeredSend_statusCode))
           endif

           IF @TriggeredSend_statusCode != "OK" THEN
               /* RaiseError(@TriggeredSend_statusMsg, 0, @TriggeredSend_statusCode, @errorCode) */
           ENDIF

           if indexof(@redirectURL,"?") > 0 then
               set @redirectURL = concat(@redirectURL,"&istokensent=",1,"&referer=",@referer)  
           else 
               set @redirectURL = concat(@redirectURL,"?istokensent=",1,"&referer=",@referer)  
           endif

        ELSE

           if indexof(@redirectURL,"?") > 0 then
               set @redirectURL = concat(@redirectURL,"&invalidpass=",1,"&referer=",@referer)  
           else 
               set @redirectURL = concat(@redirectURL,"?invalidpass=",1,"&referer=",@referer)  
           endif    

        ENDIF
        
 ELSEIF NOT EMPTY(@token) THEN

        SET @createdDate = Lookup("Tokens","CreatedDate","Token",@token)

        if @debug == 1 then
           output(concat("<br>createdDate: ", @createdDate))
        endif
        
        IF NOT EMPTY(@createdDate) AND @today < DateAdd(@createdDate, 1, "D")  THEN

           SET @endDate = DateAdd(@today, 1, "D")

           if indexof(@redirectURL,"?") > 0 then
               set @redirectURL = concat(@redirectURL,"&referer=",@referer)  
           else 
               set @redirectURL = concat(@redirectURL,"?referer=",@referer)  
           endif  

        ELSE

           if indexof(@redirectURL,"?") > 0 then
               set @redirectURL = concat(@redirectURL,"&invalidtoken=",1,"&referer=",@referer)  
           else 
               set @redirectURL = concat(@redirectURL,"?invalidtoken=",1,"&referer=",@referer)  
           endif  
         
        ENDIF
 ELSE

     if indexof(@redirectURL,"?") > 0 then
         set @redirectURL = concat(@redirectURL,"&invalidtoken=",1,"&referer=",@referer)  
     else 
         set @redirectURL = concat(@redirectURL,"?invalidtoken=",1,"&referer=",@referer)  
     endif  

 ENDIF
]%%
<script runat="server" language="javascript">

  Platform.Load("core","1");

  var debug = Platform.Variable.GetValue("@debug");
  var endDateStr = Platform.Variable.GetValue("@endDate");
  var token = Platform.Variable.GetValue("@token");

  var endDate = new Date(endDateStr);
  // Get individual components of the date and time
  var year = endDate.getUTCFullYear();
  var month = ('0' + (endDate.getUTCMonth() + 1)).slice(-2); // Add leading zero if needed
  var day = ('0' + endDate.getUTCDate()).slice(-2); // Add leading zero if needed
  var hours = ('0' + endDate.getUTCHours()).slice(-2); // Add leading zero if needed
  var minutes = ('0' + endDate.getUTCMinutes()).slice(-2); // Add leading zero if needed
  var seconds = ('0' + endDate.getUTCSeconds()).slice(-2); // Add leading zero if needed
  var milliseconds = ('00' + endDate.getUTCMilliseconds()).slice(-3); // Add leading zero if needed

  var formattedEndDate = year + '-' + month + '-' + day + 'T' + hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds + '.' + milliseconds + 'Z';

  if (debug == 1) {
      Write("<br>endDateStr: " + endDateStr)
      Write("<br>token: " + token)
      Write("<br>endDate: " + endDate)
      Write("<br>formattedEndDate: " + formattedEndDate)
  }

  Platform.Response.SetCookie("userlg", token, formattedEndDate , true);

</script>
%%[

  if @debug == 1 then
    output(concat("<hr>redirecting to: ", @redirectURL))
  else  
    redirect(@redirectURL)
  endif

]%%

Once you've validated all of the scenarios, just set @debug to 0 to disable the debugging output and enable the redirect.

Thanks Adam the code that you provided covers all the scenario and i have understood the problem of calling redirect function in between the code.

Hi Adam, As soon as i change @debug to 0 the code breaks at the line
redirect(@redirectURL)

What's the value of @redirectURL when debugging is set to 1?  Is it a valid URL?

Yes it's a valid URL, it's redirecting to another landing page
